# Converter script SQL em Linq

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-5, linq, linq-to-entities

preciso fazer a conversão do script SQL abaixo para Linq.

```
SELECT 
    [ID_Pessoa], 
    [ID_ArquivoPagamento], 
    SUM([Peculio_Valor]) AS 'Peculio_Valor' 

FROM [VW_PESSOA] 
WHERE   [ID_Pessoa] = @ID_Pessoa AND 
        [ID_ArquivoPagamento] = @ID_ArquivoPagamento  
GROUP BY [ID_Pessoa], [ID_ArquivoPagamento]
```

Abaixo o código em Linq, porém incompleto, pois não está realizando a somatória do Pecúlio:

```
 var reg = (from p in db.VW_PESSOA
            where 
            p.ID_Pessoa == item.ID_Pessoa && 
            p.ID_ArquivoPagamento == ID_ArquivoPagamento
            select new 
            {
                ID_Pessoa = p.ID_Pessoa,
                ID_ArquivoPagamento = p.ID_ArquivoPagamento,
                Peculio_Valor = p.Peculio_Valor
            }).GroupBy(p => new { p.ID_Pessoa, p.ID_ArquivoPagamento});
```

Comment: Já conhece o [Linqer](http://sqltolinq.com/)?

Comment: Não conheço @jbueno

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada

Comment: Você quer somar pelo agrupamento, certo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ficaria assim:

```
var reg = (from p in list
                       where
                       p.ID_Pessoa == item.ID_Pessoa &&
                       p.ID_ArquivoPagamento == ID_ArquivoPagamento
                       group p by new { p.ID_Pessoa, p.ID_ArquivoPagamento } into g
                       select new
                       {
                           ID_Pessoa = g.Key.ID_Pessoa,
                           ID_ArquivoPagamento = g.Key.ID_ArquivoPagamento,
                           Peculio_Valor = g.Sum(x=>x.Peculio_Valor)
                       });
```

Muda um pouco o que você fez só.

Fiz um [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/j9DV4D) para vc ver como ficaria, repara em como o List é montado, o Where está com valor fixo na variável de comparação para ficar mais fácil de entender.

Código completo do Fiddle aqui:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Program
{
    class VW_PESSOA
        {
            public string ID_Pessoa;
            public string ID_ArquivoPagamento;
            public int Peculio_Valor;
        }

    public static void Main()
    {
        List<VW_PESSOA> list = new List<VW_PESSOA>();

            list.Add(new VW_PESSOA() { ID_Pessoa = "1", ID_ArquivoPagamento = "2", Peculio_Valor= 10 });
            list.Add(new VW_PESSOA() { ID_Pessoa = "1", ID_ArquivoPagamento = "2", Peculio_Valor = 10 });
            list.Add(new VW_PESSOA() { ID_Pessoa = "4", ID_ArquivoPagamento = "3", Peculio_Valor = 10 });

            var reg = (from p in list
                       where
                       p.ID_Pessoa == "1" &&
                       p.ID_ArquivoPagamento == "2"
                       group p by new { p.ID_Pessoa, p.ID_ArquivoPagamento } into g
                       select new
                       {
                           ID_Pessoa = g.Key.ID_Pessoa,
                           ID_ArquivoPagamento = g.Key.ID_ArquivoPagamento,
                           Peculio_Valor = g.Sum(x=>x.Peculio_Valor)
                       })
                       .ToList()
                       ;

        Console.WriteLine("Reparar em como o List foi montado para entender porque o resultado é 20.");
        Console.WriteLine("A soma de Peculio_Valor onde todos os IDs = 1 e ID_arquivoPagamento = 2 é: " + reg.First().Peculio_Valor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bah, olha [isso](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dkyeDg) hahaha

Comment: Estamos de mais hoje kkkkkk. Coloca como resposta, ficou muito bom.

Comment: Capaz, a `query` tá igual a sua.